# unit testing directive with link using controller

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to unit test my directive that set form validity depending on a controller variable.
My directive code :

```js
angular.module('myModule',[])
        .directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
            scope.$watch("mailExist", function(){
                if(scope.mailExist) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('existingMailValidator', false);
                } else {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('existingMailValidator', true);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

When trying to unit test this directive, I'm trying to isolate the controller ctrl with this code:

```js
describe('directive module unit test implementation', function() {
    var $scope,
        ctrl,
        form;
   
    beforeEach(module('myModule'));
   
    beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
        $scope = $rootScope;
        var element =angular.element(
            '<form name="testform">' +
                '<input name="testinput" user-mail-check>' +
            '</form>'
        ); 
        var ctrl = element.controller('userMailCheck');
        $compile(element)($scope);
        $scope.$digest();
        form = $scope.testform;
    }));
      
    describe('userMailCheck directive test', function() {
       it('should test initial state', function() {
           expect(form.testinput.$valid).toBe(true);
       }); 
    });
});
```

Running this test, I still obtain:
 Cannot read property '$setValidity' of undefined
that's mean I haven't really inject a controller.
What is wrong in my test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally in found the solution:
first in code I have add :

```js
require: 'ngModel',
```

and then modified the unit test as follow:

```js
describe('directive module unit test implementation', function() {
    var scope,
        ngModel,
        form;
   
    beforeEach(module('myModule'));
   
    beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        var element =angular.element(
            '<form name="testform">' +
                '<input name="testinput" ng-model="model" user-mail-check>' +
            '</form>'
        ); 
        var input = $compile(element)(scope);
        ngModel = input.controller('ngModel');
        scope.$digest();
        form = scope.testform;
    }));
      
    describe('userMailCheck directive test', function() {
       it('should test initial state', function() {
           expect(form.testinput.$valid).toBe(true);
       }); 
    });
});
```

and everything works fined.